# What is Emacs <select> key?

Tags: key-bindings, terminal-emacs, keystrokes, function-key

I'm running Emacs 27.2 inside Ubuntu 16.04 in terminal mode inside a Bash version 4.3.48 shell.

- Normally the **describe-key** for the <kbd>end</kbd> keyboard key shows that it's `<end>`.
- However, when Emacs is running inside a [GNU Screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) session, the same <kbd>end</kbd> key is described by **describe-key** as `<select>`.

**Questions**:

1. What is the meaning of a `<select>` key normally and how would it be used in Emacs?
2. Would anyone know why GNU Screen translates the escape sequence for the <kbd>end</kbd> key?  Right from a bash shell it generates: `^[[F`, but under GNU Screen it generates a different escape sequence: `^[[4~`

- Note: I use `sed -n l` to reveal the escape sequence generated by a key.

Comment: `<select>` key is a pseudo-function key. So is nearly any other name within `<`...`>`. Whether such a key is defined (has a binding) is another matter. Presumably when Emacs is inside Screen such a key binding is established. Whether your keyboard has such a physical key is another matter. If you don't get a useful answer here, I suggest you consult the GNU Screen doc.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going through GNU Select docs right now.  Do you know historically what was the <select> pseudo-function for?  I'v been googling for it but did not yet find anything.  As for Emacs I'v added a user-option that allow binding that key to whatever is normally bound to <end>, but I'm curious.

Comment: Never heard of it, sorry. But maybe someone else has. Maybe Screen docs say something about it.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not find it in GNU Screen manual.  And did not find it in various old VT100 documents either. And not in space cadet keyboard either.  That's why I asked the question in the first place.

Comment: However, Microsoft document a VK_select in their virtual key codes in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995537/what-is-the-select-key for some information.